# How to construct explicit Iterator type in a field

Tags: generics, rust, traits

I tried to return an Iterator as a struct field, `dirs`:

```rust
use std::{
    fs::{self, DirEntry},
    io::Error,
    path::{Path, PathBuf},
};

struct Leds<I: Iterator<Item = PathBuf>> {
    dirs: I,
}

pub fn find_leds<P, I>(path: P) -> Leds<I>
where
    I: Iterator<Item = PathBuf>,
    P: AsRef<Path>,
{
    let paths = fs::read_dir(path).unwrap();
    let map = |dir_res: Result<DirEntry, Error>| -> Option<PathBuf> {
        if dir_res.is_err() {
            return None;
        }
        let p = dir_res.unwrap();
        let file_type = p.file_type();
        if file_type.is_err() {
            return None;
        }
        if !file_type.unwrap().is_dir() {
            return None;
        }

        return Some(p.path());
    };
    Leds {
        dirs: paths.filter_map(map),
    }
}
```

which gives an error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/dirs.rs:33:15
   |
11 | pub fn find_leds<P, I>(path: P) -> Leds<I>
   |                     - this type parameter
...
17 |     let map = |dir_res: Result<DirEntry, Error>| -> Option<PathBuf> {
   |               ----------------------------------------------------- the found closure
...
33 |         dirs: paths.filter_map(map),
   |               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected type parameter `I`, found struct `std::iter::FilterMap`
   |
   = note: expected type parameter `I`
                      found struct `std::iter::FilterMap<ReadDir, [closure@src/dirs.rs:17:15: 17:68]>`
```

Not really sure what the error tries to tell me here.

Comment: You want `impl Iterator`, not a generic parameter.

Comment: In the [linked duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74205672/alternative-ways-of-specifying-closure-as-return-type) you can apply the answer to your problem by replacing `closure` with `iterator`, and replacing `Fn` with `Iterator`.

Comment: That answer applied to your question: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=235ddb4f0d3d5039574fe5ea21559bf5